Wireguard double hop setup
I've read all the posts regarding others wireguard double hop setups but just can't make mine work. I'd appreciate any help.
I have this:  client->middleman->gateway->internet
Client config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.4/32
PrivateKey = privatekeyofclient
ListenPort=51820
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# middleman
PublicKey = publickeyofmiddleman
EndPoint = public IP of middleman:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

Middleman config:
[Interface]
10.10.10.3/32
PrivateKey = privatekeyofmiddeman
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT

#client
[Peer]
PublicKey = publickeyofclient
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.4/32
# gateway
[Peer]
PublicKey = publickeyofgateway
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = IP_address_of_gateway:51820

Gateway config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.2/32
PrivateKey = privatekeyofgateway
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -i eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
#middleman
PublicKey = publickeyofmiddleman
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.0/24
Endpoint = public_ip_of_middleman:51820

When I perform a wg show on the gateway box, I don't get a handshake, and can't ping the middleman server.
When I perform a wg show on the middleman box, I see the latest handshake to the public IP of the client.
When I perform a wg show on the client box, I see the latest handshake to the public IP of the middleman.
What do I have wrong in my setup?  I can't ping the Internet from the client and I can't ping any of the 10.10.10.x addresses.

on the gateway box, I don't get a handshake firewall?

the only firewall I have are the commands I run above.

The problem is probably from your routing on the middle box.  I suspect if you did some tcpdumps there you would see the incoming wireguard packets from the 'client' coming in one interface, and the replies to the client trying to go out over the wireguard tunnel.
